# mysql says "too many open files" when importing large *.sql file

Tags: mysql, import

I have a large database dump I want to import with MariaDB / MySQL.

```
mysql -u DBUSER DBNAME < DUMP.sql
```

The process goes on for a while, and then I get this:

```
ERROR 23 (HY000) at line 11304: Out of resources when opening file './DBNAME/' (Errcode: 24 "Too many open files")
```

When this happened to me before, I simply split the file in half and imported both halves separately. But this seems like a poor workaround.

System: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Answer (score 1):

You will need to increase the openfiles in ulimit.

More detailed info here: https://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit

Comment: Thanks! Can you summarize this in your answer? And when i have edited the file, do I need to reboot or something? Do I need to change the ulimit for myself or for mysql user? If what I want is run a mysql from the commandline.

Comment: You will need to increase it for the user mysql and restart the service mysql for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me.

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Old line was `open-files-limit = 1000`.
Something in the docs talked about `open_file_limit`.
The my.cnf also has `innodb_open_files`.

I am still not sure what is correct. Obviously the following is redundant, but it worked for me:

```
open-files-limit        = 20000
open_files_limit        = 20000
```

Others mention that one needs to look at file limits at the OS level, too..

Comment: Either syntax is accepted in `my.cnf`.

Comment: `open_files_limit` comes from the OS's ulimit.  Check out `table_open_cache`.